# Is there a way to stop users cutting and pasting content from my HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have content that has taken me a long time to create. From what I understand there is no way to stop a person getting at the content and copying it if they access the source. However is there a way to stop the users from doing a simple copy from the screen? A non jQuery way. Thanks

Comment: You could add a full-screen transparent blanket at a high z-index. That will effectively block access to the displayed content from the screen (but only from the screen). You'd have to make sure that any buttons, input fields, links, etc have a higher z-index. None of this will protect you from even a mildly determined attacker. It's probably mor trouble than it's worth.

Comment: here is a link you can refer.. http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick.html

Comment: anybody who even know how to access the developer tools of the browser will tear down the page and get the content needed anyway...so if you ask me it is not really worth the effort and plus it just gets annoying to users and a bad UI design

Comment: If you're serving it publicly, they can download the file, even if you force them to do it in a less convenient way. I'd plea here for usability's sake that you consider just including a properly written legal statement declaring your ownership and terms of use instead of breaking people's browser experience; there are plenty of reasons people right-click other than to save specific resources.

Comment: I've seen some song lyric pages that convert all their lyrics to the char-code equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Rules of the web 101: if it is on their screen, they can have it. That's because in order for the user to see content on your site, your site must first enter the realms of their territory, their turf, their house. In order for people to see your website, the stuff that is on your website must travel along the power lines that eventually leads in to their home. Once that information is in their home, it's just a matter of keeping it there. It's just the way emissions work.

*You can use tricks to make it harder* such as converting your text to an image so the user has to type it out again, but OCR can work around that, and it'll take up more precious space on your site. You can disable right click, but this is easy to work around. Not only do browser extensions exist to re-enable right clicking, Javascript could easily be turned off in any browser, breaking that protection. You could use Flash to protect your text, pretty much the same case scenario as an image. No matter what you do, the user can in some way record or recreate your content. If it is copyrighted, the only way is to use the legal system to ensure there are no unauthorized copies, but once again, the rules of the web state *if it is on their screen, they can have it.*

Some answers will probably suggest these tricks to make it harder, and you can implement them, but they are never foolproof and they might scare away what was otherwise a potential fan or customer. Since I know all this, if I see a site that disables right click I feel like the site owner doesn't know how useless it is what they're doing, and by extension don't know what they're doing at all.

Answer (score 1):

anybody who even know how to access the developer tools of the browser will tear down the page and get the content needed anyway...so if you ask me it is not really worth the effort and plus it just gets annoying to users and a bad UI design .

but even if you disregard the above paragraph then here is a link you can refer.. http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick.html

here is another way you can slow down people from copying images..

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
/* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Disable context menu on images by GreenLava (BloggerSentral.com)
Version 1.0
You are free to copy and share this code but please do not remove this credit notice.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
    function nocontext(e) {
        var clickedTag = (e==null) ? event.srcElement.tagName : e.target.tagName;
        if (clickedTag == "IMG") {
            alert(alertMsg);
            return false;
        }
    }
    var alertMsg = "Image context menu is disabled";
    document.oncontextmenu = nocontext;
//]]>
</script>
```

Now this diables right click on images that was defined with "img" tag....you can extend this to other tags as well.

But for usability sake dont do it as it is not worth it and also wont achieve anything.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. Disabling right click does not protect anything. Users can easily turn Javascript off or use various extensions to work around this code. They exist!

Comment: @tomysshadow i have said the same thing in my comments above on OP's question. This is just one of the ways to slow down somebody from copying the content... I have mentioned that in my comments. So yeah technically it is not correct but for OP's question there is no perfect answer. You put up a public page , it s content can be copied.

Comment: True, but then that should be included as part of your answer.

Comment: ok i will edit my answer to account that as well

Comment: downvote removed. Now this is a good answer

Answer (score -1):

## DO NOT DO THIS

...As if you are gonna listen to me. One of the most straightforward ways is to use the built-in event `copy`. The event is trigerred when someone copies anything from the element to which the event is attached.

```js
document.getElementById('myContent').oncopy = function() {
  /*alert("do something if you want to here")*/
  return false;
};
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<span id="myContent">Your content which you don't wanna be copied!</span>
<br/>
<input placeholder="try copying and pasting the above here to test" />
```

See the above for a simple test. You can attach the event to the `html` element to add the effect to all the elements.

## DO NOT DO THIS

P.S. Check browser support for the `copy` event.

Comment: The reason for not doing this is that it is virtually useless. And useless code should not be used.